# PL/Python. How to use None type at where clouse for integer?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

So, I have a query the same as below:

```
query = plpy.prepare(
    "SELECT count(id) FROM contracts WHERE dependent_id = $1",  
    ["integer"])

params = [dependent_id]

plpy.execute(query, params)
```

If my field `dependent_id` isn't `None`, it works well.
But, if I have a `None` at this field, query is getting work incorrect.
Because `=` isn't the same as `IS` when you compare with `NULL`

I tried to use if-else expression to correct my query string, but when query contains `IS`, I catch the syntax exception.

After I'd logged my query with `IS` keyword (when my field is `None`), I executed it in a PSQL shell, and it had worked well.

So, why `IS` doesn't work at the `plpythonu` stored procedure, but still works at the native SQL query?

#### UPDATE:

I had a discussion with DBA at my work, and he thinks it's bug in `plpythonu` with type conversion. Because `plpy.execute` rising exception when we trying to use `IS` with integer type.

After you've declared field as integer and used `IS` in query at prepare step, you will get syntax exception on execute step.

Workaround is query string with obvious indication your `None` field as `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: you can use smth like `with c(v) as (values(1),(null)) select * from c where case when v is null then v is null when v is not null then v = 1 end;` for such, or extreme option to switch on the `transform_null_equals` so `null = null` would be true. also please post code that worked as well - otherwise how do we answer why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to prepare two separate SQL statements to deal with Python's dynamic typing:

```
query = plpy.prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM contracts WHERE dependent_id = $1",  ["integer"]) if dependant_id is not None else plpy.prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM contracts WHERE dependent_id IS NULL",  [])

if dependant_id is None:
   plpy.execute(query, [])
else:
   plpy.execute(query, [dependant_id])
```

Comment: This answer is useful for me. But in more simplify construction.
`query.format("IS NULL" if dependant_id is None else "= $1")`